# Auto save form fields in react and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a parent component which is a form and it is connected to the store via redux by doing so:

```
// FormComponent
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormComponent);
```

Inside that form, I have a list of input attributes which are children components of a form:

- Form Component

  - First Name Component
  - Last Name Component
  - Address Component

I have a requirement to save changes in any field to the server by making update API call by passing JSON object that contains all attributes as soon as the input loses focus.

the API call would be something like:

```
updatePersonInfo({firstname: 'new name', lastname: 'new name', address: 'new address' });
```

My idea is to pass `PersonInfo` object as props from Form component to all children component. Each child component will update one attribute from `PersonInfo` props and dispatch UPDATE_PERSONINFO action with updated `PersonInfo` object.
But to do that, I need to connect all child component to store also:

```
// FirstNameComponent
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(FirstNameComponent);

// LastNameComponent
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LastNameComponent);

// AddressComponent
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddressComponent);
```

But my thinking that we should avoid using connect for performance reason. 
Also, I'm not convinced that I need 4 connectors to call one action.

What would be the best option to handle this scenario?

Comment: I think using redux-form may help you here.

Comment: @AliaksandrSushkevich another dependency!!!

Comment: Why not just use them directly instead of connecting them and handle the `onChange` on the parent to dispatch the action?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the API call in each of the component directly to update only the corresponding attribute, so that you can avoid Redux for this.
Eg. `updatePersonInfo({ firstname: 'new name' })`.

Your API endpoint should be a `PATCH` method that updates only the fields that are in the payload (in the above example, it should only modify the field corresponding to `firstname`).

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I can offer a good trick that I learned a while ago, in these situations we should use container component's state for creating a controlled form component and update the state on every form change, by that you can always access your form data from state of the container component. (For example: because of implementing controlled component, we can **always** send form data that is available for us from container component's state to Redux by a save button **or** in situations like your case **Focusing on another field**).

So let's get started:

**(1)** you need to use a `name` attribute and an `onChange` for each input, like so:

```
<input 
  type='text'
  name={name}
  className='form-control'
  value={value}
  onChange={onChange}/>
```

**(2)** the `onChange` function is placed in your container component and it is passed down via props to your input component and looks like this:

```
  updateCourseState(e) {
    const field = e.target.name
    const _formData = {...this.state.formData}
    _formData[field] = e.target.value // (*)
    return this.setState({ formData: _formData}) // <= then update the state on every change
  }
```

In here (*) by using precomputed dynamic variable names, we create a property for each input field in our temp _formData object and assign the target value of event that is been passed up, to it, after that we update the state.

**(3)** and finally you can now pass the state to redux when every you want, and as I read through your question you can use `Refs()` for that to keep track of when use focuses on another field you can check [this tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/tiytyGEodl0) for that and when you change the focus, here is the place that you want to send your data to Redux.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `store.subscribe(listener)` to compare any changes and calls the API to save the data. https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe

I use this for a similar feature, I save all my store data in the localstorage in the browser.

Here how I use

```
    import { loadState, saveState, loadLanguage } from "./common/localStorage";



    class Main extends React.Component {

    ..........

    store.subscribe(() => {
       saveState(store.getState()); // Some DOM api calls.
    });

    ..........

   }
```

My localStorage.js file

```
    export const loadState = () => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');

        if (serializedState === null) {
            return undefined;
        }

        return JSON.parse(serializedState);

    } catch (err) {
        return undefined;
    }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    } catch (err) {
        // die
    }
};


export const saveLanguage = (code) => {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem('languageCode', code);
    } catch (err) {
        // die
    }
};

export const loadLanguage = () => {
    try {
        const languageCode = localStorage.getItem('languageCode');

        if (languageCode === null) {
            return "pt-br";
        }

        return languageCode;

    } catch (err) {
        return "pt-br";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how your SubComponents look like (ie: FirstNameComponent...)

First, you don't really need to connect them to the store as you have the main component.

```
class FormComponent extends Component {

    changed(data, item) {
       const updatedData = {...this.props.data, item: data};
       this.props.updateData(updatedData);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FirstNameComponent onChange={this.props.update} name={this.props.data.firstname} />
                <LastNameComponent onChange={this.props.update} name={this.props.data.lastname} />
                <AddressComponent onChange={this.props.update} name={this.props.data.address} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

As you can see here, we have the "main" component that will be connected to redux.
It will get the values from the store, and it will get the method to call for updating the backend data.

The "subcomponents" are "stupid" as they just get data, and call a method from their props when an input was blurred.

Answer (score 0):

> But my thinking that we should avoid using connect for performance reason. Also, I'm not convinced that I need 4 connectors to call one action.

**Actually, using many `connect`s will result in better performance (most of the time)**.
Because of `connect` being smart enough and saving us many re-renders by using shallow-compare.

[Proof: Should I Only Connect My Top Component Or Can I Connect Multiple Components In My Tree](https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree)

Note that `connect/mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps` calculations are *relatively cheap* comparing to redundant re-renders (or DOM operations). Exception might be for complex selectors (this is what `reselect` is for).

Your case is just not complex enough and there is no big difference at all. The only difference is not performance, but a boilerplate code of `connect`ing few different component to the same store data and same actions/thunks.

And, the best option for your scenario would be to connect only form component and make input fields as simple and dumb as possible. Also, as an example, you might need to add form submit logic, or form validation - yet another points of making form component smart enough.

```
// #1
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  onChange = (e) => {
    // assuming that form component receives `person` from `mapStateToProps`
    // create new person value: previous one + updated value
    const person = {
      ...this.props.person,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }

    // update action, assuming that `updatePerson` accepts person object
    // and was injected by `mapDispatchToProps`
    updatePerson(person)
  }

  render() {
    const { person } = this.props

    // there are native HTML elements in example, you can swap with your own components
    // but, if your components will not paste name attribute value
    // you might need to use something like this: `value => this.onChange('firstName', value)
    return (
      <form>
        <input name="firstName" value={person.firstName} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input name="lastName" value={person.lastName} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input name="address" value={person.address} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

This is a simple solution. If you absolutely need to use `FirstName/LastName/AddressComponent`s then it might look like this (still, `connect`ing form component only):

```
// #2
// form's onChange handler
onChange = (name, value) => {
  const person = { ...this.props.person, [name]: value }

  this.props.updatePerson(person)
}

// form's render
<FirstNameComponent value={person.firstName} onChange={this.onChange} />

// FirstNameComponent, similar to LastName/AddressComponents
const FirstNameComponent = ({ value, onChange }) =>
  <input value={value} onChange={e => onChange('firstName', value)} />
```

---

IMO, the first one (**#1**) is simple and straightforward. Also, with better performance.

The second option (**#2**) might be OK if you have really complex logic in these input components (i.e. mask input, debounced state updates, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need redux (or redux-form) for this?

Try Formik. I found it very flexible, you can use blur handlers or validate (send only valid?) for making api calls.